# Convert a sorted list to a binary tree

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have encoded the following tree:

[image]

as

> **Unir (Unir (Unir Vacio 1 Vacio) 2 Vacio) 5 (Unir Vacio 8 Vacio)**

using the following Algebraic Data Type:

```hs
data ABB a = Vacio | Unir (ABB a) a (ABB a)
```

However, I defined the following function:

```
list2ABB :: Ord a => [a] -> ABB a
list2ABB [] = Vacio
list2ABB (x:xs) = insertABB x (list2ABB xs)
```

and when I execute:

```hs
list2ABB [1,2,5,8]
```

I get a different result:

> **Unir (Unir (Unir (Unir Vacio 1 Vacio) 2 Vacio) 5 Vacio) 8 Vacio**

Is there something wrong with my definition or encoding ?

EDIT:

Thank you everyone for the answer. Replying one of the queries, I am posting my definition of `insertABB`:

```hs
insertABB :: Ord a => a -> ABB a -> ABB a
insertABB x Vacio = Unir Vacio x Vacio
insertABB x (Unir ti y td)
    | x < y     = Unir (insertABB x ti) y td
    | x > y     = Unir ti y (insertABB x td)
    | otherwise = Unir ti y td
```

Comment: Both are equivalent, likely your `insertABB` just performs binary search and insert in a leaf, so that means that it starts with `Vacio`, and each time adds the item to the left sublist, creating thus a tree that is very skewed. There is thus no balancing in the tree.

Comment: In general, several different trees can generate the same list. So it's mathematically impossible to reconstruct the original tree from a list in all cases.

Comment: I'd guess the goal is to create a balanced binary tree. And in particular excess nodes filling up the bottom row from left to right. I think that uniquely defines the tree that should be produced and matches the example tree in the question.

Comment: @f-zer did you write `insertABB` yourself? If so, can you show how you have defined it? Perhaps that should be changed to keep the resulting tree balanced.

Comment: Inserting something in order into a binary tree that does not rebalance will leave you with a unbalances tree almost like a linked list. Your original tree was inserted 5,2,1,8, 5,8,2,1, or 5,2,8,1. All other orders would give you a different lokking tree.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have posted my definition of `insertABB`. Is that definition sensible ? Could it be improved ?

Comment: @F.Zer: it is sensical, but it will not balance the tree, since the list is ordered, it will thus each time insert it as the left-most-element and thus always at the left side of the tree, producing a linked-list-like tree, where the right subtree of all nodes are always empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `insertABB` function each time locates how the item should be inserted *without* balancing.

Since the list is sorted, and you insert it in a `foldr` like way, it will insert the items right-to-left. It will thus start with an empty tree, and then insert the rightmost element. This means that the root element will be the largest item in the list.

Next we insert an element that is smaller than the root element, so that will be the root element of the left subtree of the root tree. Next again an element that is smaller, so the left subtree of the left subtree of the root.

If the process finishes, this thus means that all right subtrees of *all* nodes will be empty, and the data is inserted in a linked-list like manner.

If you want to produce a balanced tree, you can work with a balancing tree, like an [AVL-tree <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree).

Since the list is already sorted, we can construct a complete tree. We do this by first locating the item in the middle of the list, take that as root element, and then insert the sublists as subtrees.

We can for example work with a hare and tortoise approach:

```
hareTortoise :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
hareTortoise xs = go xs xs
  where
    go [] ts = ([], ts)
    go [_] ~(t : ts) = ([t], ts)
    go (_ : _ : hs) ~(t : ts) = let ~(ya, yb) = go hs ts in (t : ya, yb)
```

We can then use this to construct the tree with:

```
constructSorted :: [a] -> ABB a
constructSorted [] = Vacio
constructSorted [x] = Unir Vacio x Vacio
constructSorted xs = let ~(ls, ~(r:rs)) = hareTortoise xs in Unir (constructSorted ls) r (constructSorted rs)
```

Comment: Amazing explanation. Thank you so much.

Comment: I followed the last suggestion in your last paragraph: ```haskell
list2ABB' :: [a] -> ABB a
list2ABB' [] = Vacio
list2ABB' xs = Unir (list2ABB' ys) z (list2ABB' zs)
  where
    n = length xs `div` 2
    m = xs !! n
    (ys, z:zs) = splitAt n xs
```

Comment: Does it make sense to you ? I am trying to construct a complete tree following `ABB a` data declaration.

Comment: Comments are a bad place for Haskell code, being whitespace sensitive.

Comment: Thank you for the hare and tortoise approach. What does `~` mean ?